# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: url is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHpxz.png)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def URL(self, ctx, *, url,):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio','noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    if not vc.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title= "노래 재생", description = "현재 " + url + "을(를) 재생하고 있습니다.", color = 0x00ff00))
    else:
        await ctx.send("노래가 이미 재생되고 있습니다!")

bot.run('Token')
```

remove 'self' but another problems is happend

and I'm from korea therefore You may not understand the exact meaning